# What is the smallest possible electronic transistor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Computers have increased in processing power mainly due to the miniaturization of transistors. I read recently that IBM, with great difficulty, shrank circuits from 14nm to 7nm but progress seems to be hitting a [wall](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/97469-is-14nm-the-end-of-the-road-for-silicon-lithography). The guiding assumption seems to be that semiconductor (Si, Ge or GaAs) transistors actually work with the minimal number of atoms forming (what would be) a completely defined crystal to make up the transistor junction and three electrodes, that could presumably be tapped somehow (initially with a scanning tunnelling microscope?) If this is not the guiding assumption then where is it leading? My questions are: What is the structure of that crystal? Do the essential properties of the semiconductors scale down 'all the way' to the molecular level? It may be impossible to make such a thing with anything resembling today's techniques but that does not preclude using radically different techniques.

Comment: Researchers have made a transistor out of one phosphorus atom: http://www.purdue.edu/newsroom/research/2012/120219KlimeckAtom.html

Comment: It's a bit impractical though because of the low temperature requirement so the question of how far conventional transistors can be scaled down still stands.

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6959/